# Dash: Get the post request query string parameters inside callback

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a multi-page dash application.

- app.py
- pages

  - page_one.py
  - page_two.py

In **app.py**, I have

```
@callback(
    Output(component_id="page-content", component_property="children"),
    Input(component_id="url", component_property="pathname"),
)
def display_page(pathname):

    if pathname == "/one":
        return page_one.layout
    elif pathname == "/two":
        return page_two.layout
```

In **page_one.py**, I have few **callbacks**.

For eg:
Callback-1

```
@callback(
    output=Output("paragraph_id", "children"),
    inputs=Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    background=True,
    running=[
        (Output("button_id", "disabled"), True, False),
        (Output("cancel_button_id", "disabled"), False, True),
        (
            Output("paragraph_id", "style"),
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
            {"visibility": "visible"},
        ),
        (
            Output("progress_bar", "style"),
            {"visibility": "visible"},
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
        ),
    ],
    cancel=Input("cancel_button_id", "n_clicks"),
    progress=[Output("progress_bar", "value"), Output("progress_bar", "max")],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_progress_A(set_progress, n_clicks):
 # Here I want to access the post request query string parameters
 some code for- A
```

Callback-2

```
@callback(
    output=Output("paragraph_id", "children"),
    inputs=Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    background=True,
    running=[
        (Output("button_id", "disabled"), True, False),
        (Output("cancel_button_id", "disabled"), False, True),
        (
            Output("paragraph_id", "style"),
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
            {"visibility": "visible"},
        ),
        (
            Output("progress_bar", "style"),
            {"visibility": "visible"},
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
        ),
    ],
    cancel=Input("cancel_button_id", "n_clicks"),
    progress=[Output("progress_bar", "value"), Output("progress_bar", "max")],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_progress_B(set_progress, n_clicks):
 # Here I want to access the post request query string parameters
 some code for- B
```

Is it possible to get the post request query string parameters inside the callback?

Please suggest.

**Updated: 1**

I have **docker services** as below:

- redis, postgres, web, celery, nginx

I have implemented demo code from dash website

```
@callback(
    output=Output("paragraph_id", "children"),
    inputs=Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    background=True,
    running=[
        (Output("button_id", "disabled"), True, False),
        (Output("cancel_button_id", "disabled"), False, True),
        (
            Output("paragraph_id", "style"),
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
            {"visibility": "visible"},
        ),
        (
            Output("progress_bar", "style"),
            {"visibility": "visible"},
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
        ),
    ],
    cancel=Input("cancel_button_id", "n_clicks"),
    progress=[Output("progress_bar", "value"), Output("progress_bar", "max")],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_progress(set_progress, n_clicks):
    total = 5

    # print("INPUTS: ", callback_context.inputs)
    # print("INPUTS: ", callback_context.inputs_list)

    for i in range(total + 1):
        set_progress((str(i), str(total)))
        time.sleep(1)

    return f"Clicked {n_clicks} times"
```

When services are **up**, I observed following things in terminal:

For **celery**:

```
celery | [tasks]
celery |   . long_callback_d0a7a49bfe3d30bfdd7a43d2a22db75123ff2fa9
```

After **button clicking**:

```
celery | [2022-12-27 20:18:43,090: INFO/MainProcess] Task long_callback_d0a7a49bfe3d30bfdd7a43d2a22db75123ff2fa9[b663bb71-6962-44a3-ae2c-00eb7d8869bf] received
proxy | 172.18.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2022:20:18:44 +0000] "POST /_dash-update-component?cacheKey=6067e37a0e1f0c07b6f9ff0d7ef0b208ae2783ba&job=b663bb71-6962-44a3-ae2c-00eb7d8869bf 
celery | [2022-12-27 20:18:49,119: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task long_callback_d0a7a49bfe3d30bfdd7a43d2a22db75123ff2fa9[b663bb71-6962-44a3-ae2c-00eb7d8869bf] succeeded in 6.027637779999964s: None
```

This is working fine.

I am trying to **get/access job parameter inside update_progress()**

so that I can use this **job parameter** to pass in the **result.AsyncResult(job)** which is celery function **inside update_progress()** to get status, state of the running task, which I am trying to use to **update progress bar**.

**Usecases:**

- Upload dataset: I'm using dcc.Upload() and file is getting uploaded successfully. e.g. user uploads data.csv
- Create train, test, dev dataset files: I'm using dbc.Button() where user clicks it and all 3 files are getting created successfully [I have used sklearn]. e.g. we get train.csv, test.csv and dev.csv
- Model training: I'm using dbc.Button() where user clicks it and model is getting generated and stored successfully. e.g. model.joblib

Comment: Can you explain better what is it you need?